# Иерархия контейнеров в MEF из Microsoft.Composition

Tags: c#, mef

В MEF из сборки `System.ComponentModel.Composition` есть возможность создавать иерархию контейнеров и использовать через дочерние контейнеры экспорты из родительских.

```
// родительский контейнер
var parentContainer = new CompositionContainer(new TypeCatalog(typeof(ParentService)));

// дочерний контейнер
var childContainer = new CompositionContainer(new TypeCatalog(typeof(Service)), parentContainer);

// использование дочерних и родительских экспортов через дочерний контейнер 
childContainer.GetExportedValue<IService>().DoWork();
childContainer.GetExportedValue<IParentService>().DoParentWork();
```

Я использую MEF 2 из NuGet-пакета [Microsoft.Composition](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Composition/). Возникла необходимость создавать иерархию контейнеров. Есть ли здесь такая же возможность? Делаю следующее:

```
var parentContainer = new ContainerConfiguration()
    .WithPart<ParentService>()
    .CreateContainer();

// Как передать сюда родительский контейнер?
var childContainer = new ContainerConfiguration()
    .WithPart<Service>()
    .CreateContainer();

childContainer.GetExport<IService>().DoWork();
childContainer.GetExport<IParentService>().DoParentWork(); // Исключение. Экспорт не найден
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, MEF 2 не поддерживает иерархию контейнеров. [Документация](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Changes&referringTitle=Documentation) на Codeplex:

> There is no catalog concept, nor composition batches, nor any
>   “container hierarchy” or composition scoping APIs.